# How to Update the values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How to update the values for popup page to landing  page using jQuery.
Ex i have asp page, from this page one another page pops up using having n number of fields
i want to update values from popup page to landing page without doing post back.
please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent's Window object can be accessed from the popup *if on the same domain* by using  `window.parent.window`.

Then jQuery can be used while specifying a custom Document (the Parent window's Document in this case) as the context, e.g.:

```
var parentDocument = window.parent.window.document
jQuery(selector, parentDocument).blah(..)
```

Where `blah(..)` represents the normal stuff to do. Be *very careful* when using closures this way - or, better, *don't* - and test in IE, which loves to partially destroy window contexts. Similarly, a function defined upon the parent's Window object could also be invoked.

There may be nicer approaches with Web Workers, but I do not use them and they are HMTL5'ish only.

Happy coding!